# Tkinter function calling on its own

Tags: python, tkinter, graphics

Using `tkinter`, I'm trying to make a ball appear on the screen then disappear (become the same color as the background) upon the "w" key being clicked, but it immediately disappears upon running the program.

I think this may be due to the structuring of the code, with the function `ball_disappear` before the variables, but I didn't notice a difference when I put the function below it. Here's the code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

height = 700
width = 1000
canvas = Canvas(width=width, height=height)
canvas_background = '#63fff9'
canvas.configure(background=canvas_background)
root.title = "Ball Bouncer Tk"

def ball_disappear():
    canvas.itemconfig(ball, fill=canvas_background, outline=canvas_background)
    canvas.update()

ballP1 = 400
ballP2 = 400
ballP3 = 600
ballP4 = 600

ball = canvas.create_oval(ballP1, ballP2, ballP3, ballP4, fill='#000000', tags="ball")

canvas.pack()
canvas.bind("w", ball_disappear())
canvas.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `ball_disappear()` to `ball_disappear` in `canvas.bind(...)`.

Comment: When I do that it doesn't make the ball turn to the background when I click "w".

Answer (score 3):

Consider this line of code:

```
canvas.bind("w", ball_disappear())
```

It has exactly the same effect as this:

```
result = ball_disappear()
canvas.bind("w", result)
```

When you bind an event, you must give it a *callable*. Typically that takes the form of a reference to a function, though it can also be the result of a call to `lambda` or `functools.partial`, or even your own function if that function returns another function.

Thus, the proper way to bind `ball_disappear` is like this:

```
canvas.bind("w", ball_disappear)
```

Your code still won't work, however, because of two other errors in your code.

First, the canvas doesn't get keyboard events by default. You must explicitly give it the keyboard focus, so sometime after creating the canvas you need to do this:

```
canvas.focus_set()
```

Second, when you bind a function to an event, the function that is called will be passed an object that has information about the event. Thus, you need to define your function like the following even if you don't plan to use the parameter in your code:

```
def ball_disappear(event):
```